# Nuxtjs - images can be loaded from HTML but not from css/scss files

Tags: image, vue.js, sass, resources, nuxt.js

Images on my page can be read from `HTML` file (for example when I have `src` tag and enter the relative path to image). For example:

```
            <span class="image"><img src="../assets/theme/images/pic01.jpg" alt=""></span>
```

But when I load image as background via `css/scss` files, they're not loaded. For example, this doesnt load image:

```js
background-image: url("/assets/theme/css/images/close.svg");

@include vendor('background-image', ('linear-gradient(to top, #{$overlay}, #{$overlay})', url("/assets/theme/images/banner.jpg")));

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to top, rgba(48, 54, 57, 0.2), rgba(48, 54, 57, 0.2)), url("/assets/theme/images/banner.jpg");
```

I have installed `file-loader` and `url-loader`. If I push `file-loader` and `url-loader` in extend section in `nuxt.config`, then images are not loaded from HTML too.

Answer (score 2):

You are using absolute path in the CSS files and nuxt doesn’t translate them. Change the address to use @ alias:

```
 background-image: url("@/assets/theme/css/images/close.svg");
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@/assets/images/something.png'

Comment: @ must be the first segment of the path. You either use relative paths or use @ at the start of the path.

Comment: In css i wrote `background: url('@/assets/images/something.png')`
On up comment shown nuxt error

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from either assets or static folder

```
.class-name {
  background-image: url('~static/images/image-name.jpg');
}

.class-name {
  background-image: url('~/static/images/image-name.jpg');
}

.class-name {
  background-image: url('~@/static/images/image-name.jpg');
}
```